# Android listView - format specific items

Tags: android, android-listview

So I'm relatively new to android programming, and currently working on a custom listView. What I'm trying to achieve is the following:

1. Retrieve a list of articles from a database.
2. Get all unique values from the 'category' column to create a list of
   categories.
3. Populate a listView with these categories
4. Add a listener for each category click which takes the user to the
   first article in that category.

I've managed to do all of the above, but now want to take it further. I have a status column in the database, where the value is either 'read' or 'unread'. What I want to do is the following:

1. If all articles in a category are 'read', to grey-out that category
   in the listview, and to ignore clicks on that particular item.

I have absolutely no idea how to format individual items within a listview...any suggestions? My code is as follows:

#### start.java:

```
public class Start extends Activity {

    private ListView mainListView ;  
    private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;  

    public static final String MYDATABASE_NAME = "questions.db";
    public static final String MYDATABASE_TABLE = "questions";
    public static final int MYDATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_CONTENT = "category";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.start);

// Query database

    SQLiteDatabase db;

    db = openOrCreateDatabase(
        "questions.db"
        , SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY
        , null
        );
    db.setVersion(1);
    db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
    db.setLockingEnabled(true);

    ArrayList<String> categoryList = new ArrayList<String>();

    Cursor cur = db.query("questions", null, null, null, null, null, null);
    cur.moveToFirst();

        while (cur.isAfterLast() == false) {

            if (categoryList.contains(cur.getString(11))) {
                // do nothing
            } else {
                // add to list
                categoryList.add(cur.getString(11));
            }
            cur.moveToNext();
        }
        cur.close();     

        Collections.sort(categoryList);
        categoryList.add(0, "All");

        // Find the ListView resource.   
        mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );  

        // Create ArrayAdapter using the category list.  
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, categoryList);    

        // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.  
        mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );       

        mainListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
                    String clickedCat = (String) mainListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    finish();
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NextClass.class);
                    myIntent.putExtra("passedCategory", clickedCat);
                    myIntent.putExtra("startTrigger", "go");
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }
        });     
}  
}
```

#### start.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black">

<TextView 
    android:text="@string/categories" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="@dimen/topbar_container" 
    android:background="@drawable/topgradient" 
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
    android:textColor="@color/primarytext" 
    android:textSize="@dimen/topbar_font" 
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="2"></TextView>

 <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"   
  android:id="@+id/mainListView"></ListView> 

</LinearLayout>
```

#### simplerow.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
 android:id="@+id/rowTextView"   
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
 android:padding="10dp"  
 android:textSize="16sp" android:textStyle="bold">  
</TextView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a ViewBinder, then call listAdapter.setViewBinder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom adapter for this:

**CustomAdapter.class:**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

    Cursor dataCursor;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    Context context;
    ArrayList<String[]> arrayList;

    public static HashMap<Integer,String> myList=new HashMap<Integer,String>();    

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor dataCursor, String[] from,
                    int[] to) {
            super(context, layout, dataCursor, from, to);

            this.context=context;
            this.dataCursor = dataCursor;
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);             

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final ViewHolder holder;

            if(convertView==null)
            {
                     convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listitem, null);
                     holder = new ViewHolder();                          

                     holder.textview=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
                             holder.layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);                              
                     convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            else
            {   
                holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }

            dataCursor.moveToPosition(position);

            String id=Integer.toString(dataCursor.getInt(dataCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id")));
            myList.put(position, id);  

            holder.textview.setText(dataCursor.getString(11));
            if(dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("index")).equals("read"))
            {               
                holder.layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);               
            }

            // other code according to the functionality you want    
            return convertView;
    }   

    static class ViewHolder
    {
            TextView textview;  
            LinearLayout layout;         
    } 
}
```

**custom_listitem.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"    
    android:background="#FFFFFF"  
    android:id="@+id/layout"  
    android:padding="5dip"     
    >
    <TextView  
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:gravity="left"      
        android:padding="5dip"  
        android:id="@+id/textview" 
    /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Now,use it in activity like:

**MainActivity.class:**

```
...
mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView ); 
Cursor cursor = db.query("questions", null, null, null, null, null, null);

CustomAdapter ca=new CustomsAdapter(context,R.layout.custom_listitem,cursor,new String[]{"id","index"},new int[]{R.id.textview,R.id.textview});

mainListView.setAdapter(ca);

mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                    long id) {

                String id=CustomAdapter.myList.get(position);
                Cursor findIndex=db.query("questions", null, "_id="+id, null, null, null, null);
                findIndex.moveToFirst();
                if(findIndex.getString(findIndex.getColumnIndex("index").equals("unread"))
                {
                     // do something for "unread" categories 
                }   
        }
});
...
```

I don't know the way,you can disable click on a particular listitem but yes,you can do the stuff under certain condition to let user feel like some of the items are unclickable.